# Using Data.Binary.decodeFile in a Yesod handler

Tags: haskell, yesod

I tried to compile the following:

```
postRQuery :: Handler RepHtml
postRQuery = do
 properties <- liftIO $ decodeFile "store" :: IO (Map String ())
 defaultLayout [whamlet|Posted!|]
```

but I got the following compiler error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `GGHandler
                              Bayith
                              Bayith
                              (Data.Enumerator.Iteratee
                               Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString IO)
                              t0'
        with actual type `IO (Map String ())'
In a stmt of a 'do' expression:
    properties <- liftIO $ decodeFile "store" :: IO (Map String ())
```

Any ideas on how I use Data.Binary.decodeFile in a Yesod handler?

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is precedence. `::` has lower precedence than `$`, so this parses as

```
properties <- (liftIO $ decodeFile "store") :: IO (Map String ())
```

while what you meant was

```
properties <- liftIO (decodeFile "store" :: IO (Map String ()))
```

Answer (score 1):

if you use ScopedTypeVariables, and you should, you can do this:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}
(properties :: Map String ()) <- liftIO $ decodeFile "store"
```

But, it seems like you're just storing Keys, why dont you use `Data.Set.Set` instead of Map